# Существует ли php-библиотека для конвертации excel и pdf

Tags: php, библиотеки, phpexcel

Вопрос в сабже, ищу такую библиотеку.
Только сложность вся в том, что на сервере стоит php5.1 и нет никакой возможности проапгрейдиться.

Поэтому `PHPEXCEL` и `mPdf` мне не подходят.
Есть ли достойные альтернативы?

Comment: Без вариантов, только хардкодить самому

Comment: @LANSELOT жесть.

Comment: @Dmitriy, ...или переходить на версию php поновее

Comment: Если нет возможности тогда стоит сказать заказчику что он не прав

Comment: Может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599221/phpexcel-save-pdf